# how to pass a link from xml file to xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, hyperlink, parameter-passing, argument-passing

I have a short question. I have a link.xml file which contains a link location like:

```
<xml>
<property name="link" value="www.something.com/somethinggood">
</xml>
```

or it could be like:

```
<xml>
<link>www.something.com/somethinggood</link>
</xml>
```

and i need to pass it to xslt whick contains  a href tag:

```
    <td>
    <a href=" link " target="_blank"> somethinggood </a>
    </td>
```

How can i pass that link from my xml file to xsl file?

Thank you for Your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need two XSLT rules for this:

```
<xsl:template match="property[@name='link']">
  <a href="{@value}"><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@value, '/')"/></a>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="link>
  <a href="{text()}"><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(text(), '/')"/></a>
</xsl:template>
```

In the more general case in which the URL contains slashes before the site address we will still have to tune this a little bit.